# Identifying actress/character that's one of the Bounty Hunters in Dark Matter

Tags: character-identification, actor-identification, dark-matter

Ryo Ishida has recently taken on some bounty hunters to

> Hunt down and kill the crew of the Raza as well as retrieve the blink drive...

I don't think we've ever been informed of the names of the bounty hunters, however one of the actresses looks frustratingly familiar but I can't seem to put a name to the face and IMDB isn't being particularly useful.

[image]

Is anyone able to identify the actress (and maybe character name)?

Comment: I had a look at the credits and couldn't see any names given to the bounty hunters :(

Comment: @Katdragon indeed... Also couldn't find anything via image search. There's only been one hunter that's been on screen more than a few seconds (where I think a name is mentioned). It's hard to tell if any more will play a role... I'm sure I've seen that actress in other things though...

Comment: You could ask on Joseph Malozzi's blog or twitter (@BaronDestructo). He's generally pretty good about answering.

Comment: I've reached out to Joseph Mallozzi on twitter (https://twitter.com/robertwrayuk/status/904647922482020357), he's probably a little busy trying to get someone other than SyFy to pick up Dark Matter at the moment though =(

Comment: @Rob oh... I'd completely forgotten about this question... I think I sent a tweet and he may have responded... I just never chased things up... errrr... yeah... but seriously - what the heck do Syfy think they're doing!!!!? (angry face)

Comment: @JonClements, the same thing they usually do when a show turns out to be fantastic,... :/

Comment: From Joseph Mallozzi (https://twitter.com/BaronDestructo/status/904710745597890560): *Hmm.  I recall the names of the two female bounty hunters were Andrea and Shannon, but I don't know their last names off the top of my head.* with a bit of luck that nuggest of info might be enough for someone else to work it out (I'm assuming he's given first names of the actresses!) =)